# SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 17 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am getting error like I am just console the success response and error response, but It is printing like below

Comment: Hi! More info is needed to can help you!

Comment: I'm getting  error when I've return the data in json format

Answer (score 0):

Please check your api is returning a valid JSON response. Ideally this error occurs when backend api is returning a data is JSON. Many times its happens that if calling API is not authenticated its return login html and if angular tries to parse it as json it throw the above error.

Comment: I've checked everywhere, but it's happening same. I'v created login api and send a data json like that
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Can you inspect your call in network tab in devtool and see whats the reponse your are getting?